# Редирект с www на без www за исключением файла robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

Делаю в файле .htaccess редирект с www на основной хост таким образом:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы это правило не распространялось на robots.txt, то есть не было редиректа по адресу http://www.site.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что еще один `RewriteCond` вида

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots\.txt
```

перед `RewriteRule` вам поможет.

Comment: Тогда robots.txt доступен только с www, если ввести без www происходит редирект на www. Можно сделать так, чтобы robots.txt был доступен и с www, и без?